# Loopback v3 add column to Table -> "Unknown column 'column_name' in 'field list'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, loopbackjs

I have a webshop based on React with a Loopback rest api. Now i want to add new columns to the client Table. If i add the object as property option to the client.js the error shows "Unknown column 'gender_delivery' in 'field list'". See the image below. The comments are not included in the saved code.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "plural": "clients",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "allowEternalTokens": true,
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "ttl": 43200,
  "mixins": {
  "DisableAllMethods": {
    "hide": [
      "prototype.__create__orders",
      "prototype.__delete__orders",
      "prototype.__destroyById__orders",
      "prototype.__updateById__orders",
      "prototype.__count__cart",
      "prototype.__create__cart",
      "prototype.__destroy__cart",
      "prototype.__update__cart",
      "prototype.__destroyById__cart",
      "prototype.__findById__cart",
      "prototype.__addArticle__cart",
      "prototype.__updateById___cart",
      "prototype.__addArticles__cart",
      "reset"
    ]
  },
  "TimeStamp": {
    "createdAt": "created_at",
    "updatedAt": "updated_at",
    "required": false,
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "silenceWarnings": false
  }
},
"restrictResetPasswordTokenScope": true,
"emailVerificationRequired": true,
"hidden": [
  "password",
  "verificationToken",
  "securityQuestion",
  "securityQuestion",
  "verificationHash"
],
"properties": {
  "id": {
    "type": "number",
    "id": true,
    "generated": true,
    "mysql": {
      "columnName": "id",
      "dataType": "int",
      "dataLength": null,
      "dataPrecision": 11,
      "dataScale": 0,
      "nullable": "N"
    }
  },
  "oid": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "username": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "password": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "disable": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "required": true,
    "default": false
  },
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "first_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "middle_name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "last_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "street": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "city": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "telephone": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "fax": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "email": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "deleted": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "required": true,
    "default": false
  },
  "title": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "zip": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "country": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "company": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "lastlogin": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "is_online": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "required": true,
    "default": false
  },
  "password_orig": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "gender": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "telephone2": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "iscompany": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "companyid": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "houseno": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "addressadditional": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "tax": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "required": true,
    "default": true
  },
  "tax_type": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "securityQuestion": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "securityAnswer": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "verificationHash": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "showTutorial": {
    "type": "boolean",
    "default": true
  },


  // NEW COLUMNS
  "gender_delivery": {
    "type": "number"
  },
  "first_name_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "last_name_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "addressadditional_delivery": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "street_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "houseno_delivery": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "zip_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "city_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  },
  "country_delivery": {
    "type": "string",
    "required": true
  }



},
"validations": [],
"relations": {
  "cart": {
    "type": "hasOne",
    "model": "cart",
    "foreignKey": "clientId",
    "primaryKey": "id"
  },
  "addresses": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "address",
    "foreignKey": "clientId",
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
  },
  "orders": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "order",
    "foreignKey": "clientId",
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "project",
    "foreignKey": "clientId",
    "options": {
      "nestRemoting": true
    }
  }
},
"acls": [
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "create"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "deleteById"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "login"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "logout"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "findById"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "patchAttributes"
  },
  {
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "replaceById"
  },
  {
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "verify"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "verifyAccount"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "clearPassword"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "changePasswordPublic"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "confirm"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$everyone",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "resetPassword"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$authenticated",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "changePassword"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$authenticated",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "setPassword"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "deleteById"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "exists"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "find"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "findById"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "upsert"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "admin",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "updateAll"
},
{
  "accessType": "EXECUTE",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "updateClientAttributes"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__findById__accessTokens"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__count__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__create__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__delete__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__destroyById__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__findById__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__addArticle__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__updateById___cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__addArticles__cart"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__count__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__create__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__delete__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__destroyById__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__findById__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__updateById__addresses"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__count__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__create__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__delete__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__destroyById__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__findById__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__updateById__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__createPdf__orders"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__count__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__create__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__delete__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__destroyById__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__findById__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__get__projects"
},
{
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "$owner",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "__updateById__projects"
 }
],
"methods": {}
}
```

The weird thing is that whenever i do the same with another Table it works perfectly fine. See example generas.

```
{
  "name": "genera",
  "plural": "generas",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "IgnoreDeleted": true,
    "RowCounter": true,
    "TimeStamp": {
      "createdAt": "created_at",
      "updatedAt": "updated_at",
      "required": false,
      "validateUpsert": true,
      "silenceWarnings": false
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "generated": true,
      "mysql": {
        "columnName": "id",
        "dataType": "int",
        "dataLength": null,
        "dataPrecision": 11,
        "dataScale": 0,
        "nullable": "N"
      }
    },
    // SEE EXAMPLE TEST 
    "TEST": {
      "type": "number"
    },



    "oid": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false
    },
    "lang": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    },
    "name1": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "name2": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "deleted": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    },
    "hidden": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "required": true,
      "default": false
    },
    "sortscount": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "categories": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "genera_category",
      "foreignKey": "generaId",
      "through": "generas_categories_mm",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    },
    "arts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "art",
      "foreignKey": "generaId",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    },
    "sorts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "sort",
      "foreignKey": "generaId",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
  },
  "methods": {}
}
```

In Addition i've tried runing yarn update tables. This command doesn't run either. It says. Cannot read 'connector' of undefined.
Here is the code inside my drop-tables.js

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
/* jshint node: true */

'use strict';

const server = require('../server/server');
const ds = server.dataSources.mySqlIds;

const models = require('../server/model-config.json');

const tables = [];

const keys = Object.keys(models);

keys.forEach(key => {
  const model = models[key];
  if (key[0] !== '_' && model.dataSource === 
'mySqlIds') {
    tables.push(key);
  }
});

const dropTablePromises = [];

console.log(tables);

tables.map(table => {
  const dropTable = new Promise(function(resolve, 
reject) {
    ds.connector.dropTable(
      table, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log(`\tDrop table "${table}".`);
          resolve({name: table, data: data});
        }
      });
  });
  dropTablePromises.push(dropTable);
});

console.log('1. DROP TABLES');

Promise.all(dropTablePromises)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  .then(() => ds.disconnect());
```

The result of server.dataSources is an empty object = {}
that explains why it says 'ds' is undefined. (It doesn't work with datasources either).

My goal is just to extend the clients table by a few properties.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide all text as text, not as pictures of text. Search engines and visually impaired people cannot divine anything from an image. See [ask] where it says "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Done!